# How do I actually disable F11-fullscreen on Lubuntu 13.04?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, lxde, fullscreen

I have already deleted the entry for F11-fullscreen from ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml

even after a reboot, the F11 fullscreen functionality remains, and I can't use F11 in other applications as the key press is intercepted.

Comment: Are those applications system applications like terminal or nautilus? Because removing F11 binding from `lxde-rc.xml` seems to work for me and I can use that key in `Eclipse`. However it still works as full screen for system apps. These may be because these applications themselves listen for F11 and switch to full screen. Thus you may need to edit the config for these individual applications aswell.

Answer (score 14):

I think just deleting the lines for `F11` may not serve the purpose.

You need to replace the contents after `action name=` to nothing.

So, change `action name="ToggleFullscreen"` to `action name=""`, save the file, and then run `openbox --reconfigure` in a terminal. There should be no error message if your `lubuntu-rc.xml` is in good condition! There's no need to reboot. Now, `F11` should have no effect as far as Openbox is concerned.

I don't know about your other programs which also want to use `F11` for something else. For example, both Firefox and Google Chrome will still use `F11` to toggle full screen. On the other hand, `F11` in LibreOffice will now function to open the "Style and Formatting" panel.