# Putty through Wine - F11 need to send, not make full screen

Tags: ssh, keyboard, shortcut-keys, wine, putty

I'm trying to convert our sales team to running Ubuntu/Lubuntu systems. Our primary Point-Of-Sale uses Putty's SSH terminal to connect to a Red-Hat server.

We had to run the Windows version of Putty as the Linux version doesn't allow for live re-sizing of Windows as our sales team will share the desktop with 2 or 3 terminals at a time.

Things were going well until someone noticed that as we enter various screens thought function keys <kbd>F6</kbd> / <kbd>F7</kbd> / <kbd>F12</kbd> etc.

The other function keys work fine, but <kbd>F11</kbd> no longer brings us to the screen we need, it just toggles app to move in/out of full-screen mode (just like web browsers).

In Putty settings - *Terminal* -> *Keyboard* -> *Function Keys and Keypad* - Must be set to SCO. I've tried the others with no luck.

I've also tried this with the Linux version of Putty and still have the same issue. I've searched pretty hard, but am not seeing this exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml seems to have done the trick for me thanks to this thread below.

[How do I actually disable F11-fullscreen on Lubuntu 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354664/how-do-i-actually-disable-f11-fullscreen-on-lubuntu-13-04)